# Python Pandas: Convert 2,000,000 DataFrame rows to Binary Matrix (pd.get_dummies()) without memory error?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, bigdata

I am processing a large file of records with `2,000,000` rows. Each line contains features about emails and a binary label `[0,1]` for non-spam or spam respectively.

I want to convert all features such as `email_type` which takes on values from `[1,10]` to a binary matrix.

This can be accomplished using `pd.get_dummies()`, which creates a binary matrix from a column of features.

This works perfectly on a small subsample of the data, say `10,000` rows. However, for `100,000+` rows, I see the error `Killed:9`.

To tackle this, I have tried the following:

Steps:

1. Split the DataFrame into chunks of 10,000 rows using `numpyp.array_split()`
2. Create a binary matrix for each DataFrame of 10,000 rows
3. Append these to a list of DataFrames
4. Concatenate these DataFrames together (I am doing this to preserve the difference in columns that each block will contain)

Code:

```
# break into chunks
chunks = (len(df) / 10000) + 1
df_list = np.array_split(df, chunks)
super_x = []
super_y = []

# loop through chunks
for i, df_chunk in enumerate(df_list):
    # preprocess_data() returns x,y (both DataFrames)
    [x, y] = preprocess_data(df_chunk)
    super_x.append(x)
    super_y.append(y)

# vertically concatenate DataFrames
super_x_mat = pd.concat(super_x, axis=0).fillna(0)
super_y_mat = pd.concat(super_y, axis=0)

# pickle (in case of further preprocessing)
super_x_mat.to_pickle('super_x_mat.p')
super_y_mat.to_pickle('super_y_mat.p')

# return values as np.ndarray
x = super_x_mat.values
y = super_y_mat.values
return[x, y]
```

Some example output:

```
chunks 13
chunk 0 2016-04-08 12:46:55.473963
chunk 1 2016-04-08 12:47:05.942743
...
chunk 12 2016-04-08 12:49:16.318680
Killed: 9
```

Step 2 (Conversion to binary matrix) is out of memory after processing `32` blocks (`320,000` rows), however the out of memory could occur as the chunk is appended to a list of dataframes as follows `df_chunks.append(df)`.

Step 3 is out of memory trying to concatenate `20` successfully processed blocks (`200,000` rows)

The ideal output is `numpy.ndarray` that I can feed to a `sklearn` Logistic Regression classifier.

What other approaches can I try? I am starting to approach machine learning on datasets this size more regularly.

I'm after advice and open to suggestions like:

1. Processing each chunk, using all possible columns from entire dataframe and saving as file before re-combining
2. Suggestions of file data storage
3. Completely other approaches using different matrices

Comment: Your data don't seems to be so big, so the problem must be somewhere else. Perhaps more dummies than you think ? can we see df.head() ?

Comment: Currently approx 620 dummies, although we like to extend to an additional 15,000 dummies

Comment: Waouh ! in your post you  propose [0,10], so I did'nt understand the problem. So your memory crash is normal since 600 * 100.000 is the magnitude of a PC memory space. I guess you have to find  an other approach to manage your data : binary matrix with so much dummies is dramatically inefficient.

Comment: Sorry! I guess `email_type` was a misleading example. A column for `location` has many more values. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry. I know nothing in Logistic Regression classifier ....

Comment: I think that if you have that many dummies, you're probably doing something wrong. I doubt there's any information to get from performing a logistic regression on that many dummy variables, and a tree-based algorithm is probably going to help you here ([this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) for example). ...

Comment: ... If you still want to go with this, you should probably try to split in chunks, dump them in files and then read them, generate the dummies, and save them back, one at a time. That will generate dummies, but you will still have the problem of putting everything together for your analysis. Can't do much about your computer's limit.

Comment: @jfive can you walk me through your code for the `preprocess_data` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are doing something like one-hot encoding, or in any case are going to have lots of zeros, have you considered using [sparse matrices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html)? This should be done after the pre-processing e.g.:

```
[x, y] = preprocess_data(df_chunk)
x = sparse.csr_matrix(x.values)
super_x.append(x)
```

pandas also has a [sparse type](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html):

```
x=x.to_sparse()
[x, y] = preprocess_data(df_chunk)
super_x.append(x)
```

One note: since you are cutting and joining by row, csr is preferable to csc.